# Create a claim form for devise on rails by replicating the forget password form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, user-accounts, forgot-password

I have a system in place where people need to claim accounts already set in a database by proving that they own the same email address. Every user in the user database has a password generated by Devise using the friendly token, so that people can still just login via omniauth plugins.

The current method I have planned out is to create a separate version of password#new (from Devise) as the 'claim' form, but I'm not too sure where to go from there. Do I have to create a whole new model? or can I just create a PasswordsController and config routes to go to a new view?

Comment: So you already have the email adresses in the users table which could be activated?

Comment: Yes I do, all I need is to replicate the forget password page into a separate page with a different URL and some of the text on the page altered, but the functionality is equal.

Comment: Then you should check the [github devise wiki's](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) how-to articles.